# ¿Alguien puede ayudarme en la creación de esta bd con el sql?(Error en las claves ajenas tabla cursos-grupos en mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Extraescolares;
USE Extraescolares;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursos;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cursos (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  codigo varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  ensenanza varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  abreviatura varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  nombre_cas varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  nombre_val varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  idPadre int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS grupos;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grupos (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  codigo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  nombre varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  ensenanza varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  linea varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  turno varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  modalidad varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  aula varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  capacidad smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  tutor_ppal varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  tutor_sec varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  oficial varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cursos-grupos;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cursos-grupos (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  grupo varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  ensenanza varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  curso varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (grupo) REFERENCES grupos(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (curso) REFERENCES cursos(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS alumnos;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alumnos (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  NIA varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  nombre varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  apellido1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  apellido2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_nac varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  municipio_nac varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  municipio_nac_ext varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  provincia_nac varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  pais_nac varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  nacionalidad varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  sexo varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  tipo_doc varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  documento varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  expediente varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  libro_escolaridad varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  cod_postal varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  tipo_via varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  domicilio varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  numero varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  puerta varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  escalera varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  letra varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  piso varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  provincia varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  municipio varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  localidad varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  telefono1 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  telefono2 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  telefono3 varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  email1 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  email2 varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  sip varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  observaciones varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  ampa varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  seguro varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  dictamen varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_resolucion varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  informe_psicoped varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  informado_posib varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_matricula varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  fecha_ingreso_centro varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  estado_matricula varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  tipo_matricula varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  repite varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  num_repeticion varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  ensenanza varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  curso varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  grupo varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  turno varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  linea varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  trabaja varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  fuera_comunidad varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  matricula_parcial varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  matricula_condic varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  informe_medico varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  banco varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  sucursal varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  digito_control varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  cuenta varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  modalidad varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  iban varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (curso) REFERENCES cursos(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  FOREIGN KEY (grupo) REFERENCES grupos(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Professor;
CREATE TABLE Professor(
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    abreviatura varchar (50),
    nom varchar(60),
    correu varchar(60)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Extraescolar;
CREATE TABLE Extraescolar (
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nom varchar (60),
    dataEixida datetime,
    nAsistents int (6),
    preu double,
    dataLimit datetime,
    dataPagament datetime
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS GestioAlumnes;
CREATE TABLE GestioAlumnes(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idExtraescolar int,
    idAlumne int,
    idProPagat int ,
    idProAuto int,
    pagat boolean DEFAULT false,
    autoritzacio boolean DEFAULT false,

    FOREIGN KEY (idExtraescolar) REFERENCES Extraescolar(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idAlumne) REFERENCES Alumne(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idProPagat) REFERENCES Professor(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idProAuto) REFERENCES Professor(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `GestioExt
raescolar`;
CREATE TABLE GestioExtraescolar(
 id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    idExtraescolar int,
    idPro int,
    gestor boolean DEFAULT false,
    lector boolean DEFAULT false,

    FOREIGN KEY (IdExtraescolar) REFERENCES Extraescolar(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (IdPro) REFERENCES Professor(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Hola Paco, por favor, edita la pregunta para ofrecer más información sobre el planteamiento del problema, cuáles son las dificultades y los posibles errores que tengas al ejecutar tu código. De esta forma, podrás recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!